# Lato font rendering Safari

Tags: css, fonts, safari, rendering

I have a problem with 'Lato' font rendering in Safari. In chrome, opera and firefox it works without problems. Check it out [live](http://machycek.me)

---

-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased

didn't help

---

Thanks for your time.
Have a nice day.

Comment: A "problem", such as??

Comment: When the "introduction" animation triggers the text is not rendered. After the animation ends then it's rendered. (on retina MBP)